# How to filter array data in TreeMap

Tags: java, android-studio, hashmap

I have an array of data like below:

```
15-01-2023 16:23:45.692:[0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 81.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    15-01-2023 16:23:45.693:[0.0, 0.0, 61.0, 81.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    15-01-2023 16:23:45.694:[0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 34.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    15-01-2023 16:23:45.695:[0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 34.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    15-01-2023 16:23:45.696:[0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 34.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    15-01-2023 16:23:45.697:[0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 34.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 26.0, 22.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

can I select data at the third index greater than 50, so if in a row of data the third index is less than 50 then the data will not be saved to the map:

focus on the starred data, so if the starred data is more than 50 it will be saved to the map. **this data will be save on map**.

```
15-01-2023 16:23:45.692:[0.0, 0.0, **61.0**, 81.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
15-01-2023 16:23:45.693:[0.0, 0.0, **61.0**, 81.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

but if the starred data is less than 50, then the data will not be stored in the hashmap. **will not save to the map because the data on index 2 less than 50**

```
15-01-2023 16:23:45.694:[0.0, 0.0, **21.0**, 34.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
15-01-2023 16:23:45.695:[0.0, 0.0, **21.0**, 34.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
15-01-2023 16:23:45.696:[0.0, 0.0, **21.0**, 34.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 78.0, 62.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
15-01-2023 16:23:45.697:[0.0, 0.0, **21.0**, 34.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 26.0, 22.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 21.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 49.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 10.0, 16.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I've try this code but doesn't work :

```
private Double r_data_double_arr[] = new Double[89];

Map<String,Object> rightDataDict = new TreeMap<>();
Map<String,Object> rightDataDictCon = new TreeMap<>();

Date date = new Date();

String a = Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr);

if (a.indexOf(2) > 50){
        rightDataDict.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)), a);
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting your array to string? And why are you using a map of `Map<String,Object>` instead of `Map<Date, Double[]>` ?

Comment: is it wrong? what is the correct path

Comment: Where does the data come from and how do you recieve it?

Comment: you can check full code here https://pastebin.com/Q9jgxnGN

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I undersand what you are trying to do. But with out changing a lot of what you already have, something like below should work: Check the value before converting to string

```
Date date = new Date();

if (l_data_double_arr[2] > 50){
    String a = Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr);
    rightDataDict.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)), a);
}
```

Side note: you don't really need the redudant `String.valueOf` which is all over your code if the method you are calling already returns a string. So I would change it to

```
if (l_data_double_arr[2] > 50){
    String a = Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr);
    rightDataDict.put(formatter.format(date), a);
}
```